# In pipe I am sending something but receives different

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

In this code, I am trying to input a string from the child process and reverse it in parent and print the result in the child process.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd) != -1){
        printf("Into pipe\n");
        int id = fork();
        
        if(id == 0){
            close(fd[0]);
            char msg[100];
            scanf("%s", msg);
            printf("Set message is: %s\n", msg);
            write(fd[1], msg, sizeof(msg));
            close(fd[1]);   
            sleep(1);       
        }
        
        else{
            close(fd[1]);
            char get_msg[100];
            char rev_msg[100];
            
            read(fd[0], get_msg, sizeof(get_msg));
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("Get message is: %s\n", get_msg);
            for(int i=0; i<strlen(get_msg); i++)
                rev_msg[i] = get_msg[strlen(get_msg)-i-1];
            
            printf("Reverse message is :%s\n", rev_msg);
            
            write(fd[1], rev_msg, sizeof(rev_msg));
            close(fd[1]);
            
            sleep(3);
        }
        
        if(id == 0){
            close(fd[1]);
            char getting_msg[100];
            read(fd[0], getting_msg, sizeof(getting_msg));
            printf("Received reverse message is :%s\n", getting_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see the reverse string is not passing from the parent to child process
What I am trying to get is
**Received reverse string = Reverse message.**
Cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: The child closed `fd[0]`.  The read on `fd[0]` will certainly fail.

Comment: Since the read failed, you invoke undefined behavior and `getting_msg` just happens to be in the same place on the stack as the previous variable `msg`.  Try `char getting_msg[100] = "this is an initializer";` and see what happens.

Comment: If you need two-directional communication, you need two pipes. You also don't need to split the child-process code into two different parts, and I really recommend that you put it in a separate function. And also that you do the console-input (`scanf`) in the parent process. Lastly, ***always*** do error checking! Besides the `pipe` Call you will never know if any of the function you call fail, not even the `fork` call. And if `pipe` fail you're not reporting it, the program will just end silently.

Comment: @William Pursell now the message i get is "this is an initializer" but how can I solve it can you please help

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so is something is occurring which is bad to my program.

Comment: Besides the child closing the read-end of the pipe before it tries to read, and closing the write-end twice, and using the same single pipe for two-way communication (which it's not really made for), and generally not checking for errors?

Comment: Thanks it helps closing ends is a bad idea

Comment: Emphasis on @Someprogrammerdude 's recommendation.  *Always* do error checking.  Check the value returned by `read` to see if it actually read any data.